# South won't migrate my custom field

Tags: django, django-models, python-2.7, django-south, django-1.3

I have a model which has a nullable foreign key relation with itself (this 'self' can be any model which has this foreign key). This foreign key is a custom class which prevents cyclic relationships.

The call to `super()` in the `__init__` contains `null=True` and `blank=True` and therefor need to be included in the inspection rules of South. This makes at least the *schemamigration* work, but the *migrate* still fails.

Following code shows: the custom foreign key, the inspection rules and the model using the foreign key.

```
# Foreign key
class ParentField(models.ForeignKey)
    def __init__(self, verbose_name=None, **kwargs):
        super(ParentField, self).__init__('self', verbose_name=verbose_name, null=True, blank=True, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def checkcyclic(object, attr):
        '''Check for a cyclic relationship'''
        pass

# Introspection rules
add_introspection_rules([
    (
        [ParentField],
        [],
        {
            'null': ['null', {'default': True}],
            'blank': ['blank', {'default': True}],
        }
    )
], ["^test\.models\.fields\.ParentField"])

# Model
class Relation(Model):
    parent = ParentField(related_name='child_set')
```

Migrating gives the following error:

```
$ ./manage.py migrate
[..]
super(ParentField, self).__init__('self', verbose_name=verbose_name, null=True, blank=True, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for keyword argument 'to'
```

I've tried addding a rule like below, but that changed nothing.

```
'to': ['rel.to', {'default': 'test.models.Relation'}],
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing the wrong way or any hints to a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end this solution worked for me, credits to Shai over at googlegroups:

South, when it tries to build an instance of your custom field, collects (using
the rules) values for the different kwargs of your class. One of these is the
`"to"` argument; you see it specified in the migration code.

Then, it takes the values it collected and passes them to a constructor. So,
effectively, you get the call

```
fields.ParentField(related_name='set', to=orm['module.ModelClass'])
```

However, inside your `__init__` this gets translated to

```
models.ForeignKey('self', related_name='set', to=orm['module.ModelClass'])
```

So there are two values for the `'to'` argument -- the first is the positional
`'self'`.

One solution, at least, is to do the same thing I recommended for the null and
blank arguments -- add it into kwargs, rather than directly to the call.

```
kwargs.setdefault('to', 'self')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but solved it by calling: `kwargs.pop('to', None)`.

However, there was next error:

```
File "/.../django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 973, in resolve_related_fields
    to_field = (self.rel.to._meta.pk if to_field_name is None
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

This was because I was passing model name as a string not class instance. South doesn't support that. Fixed by importing model and using it instead of string.

Full working example below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

from django.db.models.loading import get_model

def _get_user_model():
    """Import django.contrib.auth.models.User or other model set in settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL"""
    model_name = getattr(settings, 'AUTH_USER_MODEL', 'auth.User')
    return get_model(*model_name.split('.', 1))

def _set_default_kwargs(kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault('on_delete', models.SET_NULL)
    kwargs.setdefault('blank', True)
    kwargs.setdefault('null', True)
    kwargs.pop('to', None) # Remove kwargs['to'] parameter set by south migrations
    return kwargs

class ForeignKeyWithUser(models.ForeignKey):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs = _set_default_kwargs(kwargs)
        User = _get_user_model()
        return super(ForeignKeyWithUser, self).__init__(User, **kwargs)

try:
    from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules
    add_introspection_rules([], ["^toolkit\.models\.fields\.ForeignKeyWithUser"])
except ImportError:
    pass
```